# OnCollisionEnter2D only gets called once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two objects in my scene, one which only has a `BoxCollider2D` (*the Column class*) and the second object has a `Rigibody2D` as well as its own `BoxCollider2D` (*Player class*).

I added a script to the first object to have an `OnCollisionEnter2D`. I see it gets triggered when my second object collides with it, and it bounces my 2nd object back when it tries to enter.

I do see my `OnCollisionEnter2D` method getting called. But if I move my 2nd object again to my first object it gets bounced back again, however I don't see my `OnCollisionEnter2D` method getting called the 2nd time.

Is this intended behavior? If so, what method would get called every time a collision occurs between these two objects?

**Note:** I saw `OnCollisionStay2D` get called a few more times and then it stopped. I assume this is when it's bouncing my 2nd object out. I also see that `OnCollisionExit2D` never got called. I zoomed into the editor and saw clearly the green lines of the BoxCollider2D did not overlap between my objects so it should've exited the collision when it bounces it back.

```c#
public class Column : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D columnColl;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        columnColl = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
          Debug.Log("Collision Exit");
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
       //Debug.Log("Collision Stayed");
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision Happened");
    }
}
```

and

```c#
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xMoveSpeed = 1f;
    private Rigidbody2D rbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            rbody.position = rbody.position + new Vector2(xMoveSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code as well?

Comment: I updated the original post with the code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "manually" change [`rbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html).

Rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

> Use Rigidbody.MovePosition to move a Rigidbody, complying with the Rigidbody's interpolation setting.
>
> If Rigidbody interpolation is enabled on the Rigidbody, calling `Rigidbody.MovePosition` results in a smooth transition between the two positions in any intermediate frames rendered. This should be used if you want to continuously move a rigidbody in each `FixedUpdate`.
>
> Set `Rigidbody.position` instead, if you want to **teleport a rigidbody** from one position to another, with no intermediate positions being rendered.

You also should rather do it in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) which is used for the Physics instead of `Update`

```c#
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        rbody.MovePosition(rbody.position + new Vector2(xMoveSpeed, 0);
    }
}
```

---

Also make sure at least one of the objects is **not** `kinematic` as to [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html):

> Collision events are **only sent if** one of the colliders also has a **non-kinematic** rigidbody attached.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the movement to MovePosition() as suggested, the movement seems alot smoother now. However, the problem still persist in that OnCollisionEnter2D() still only get called once and Exit is never called even though I the box collide lines are not overlapping. My Player Object is not Kinematic while the column is. Could this be an issue with the sprites? I attached my project files for the details: https://www.dropbox.com/s/38azi36lb5mph4o/TestProject.zip?dl=0